# best way to handle multiple streams to same file

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety, filestream

I am trying to create a binary storage. Files once added, can't be deleted. All files are stored in the same master file (storage.bin). i will have a table index with pairs of (key, startFilePos, fileLength).

I am struggling to find the best solution before i start coding. As i am not that familiar with streams under .net, i would like some advice on them.

1. are multiple streams to the same file (storage.bin) a solution?
   As files may be added in parallel, once i start receiving a file, i
   reserve the space on disk for it and start writing that specific
   file to the reserved block while other same-scenario files are added
   on other threads.
2. if (1) is a viable solution, is it the optimal one? if not, could
   you point to a better one?
3. what is the best way to allocate threads for every file-add scenarios? It seems like 1 thread/ 1 stream isn't a viable solution. What i was thinking is to have a a thread pool and if the limit is reached, have a new file wait for one to be available.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. are multiple streams to the same file (storage.bin) a solution? As files may be added in parallel, once i start receiving a file, i
>      reserve the space on disk for it and start writing that specific file
>      to the reserved block while other same-scenario files are added on
>      other threads.

Yes, this could be a solution. As long as the different streams are writing to different non-overlapping segments of the file there will be no problems.

> 2. if (1) is a viable solution, is it the optimal one? if not, could you point to a better one?

Use separate files and keep the index in the master file.

> 3. what is the best way to allocate threads for every file-add scenarios? It seems like 1 thread/ 1 stream isn't a viable solution.
>      What i was thinking is to have a a thread pool and if the limit is
>      reached, have a new file wait for one to be available

You've just described how a thread pool works. Before rolling your own, make sure you have checked the [`ThreadPool`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool(v=vs.110).aspx) class built directly into the framework. Or a custom [`concurrency limiting task scheduler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee789351(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Regarding (2), i am constrained by the specific problem to handle all in a single file. If it was up to me, i would keep separate files.

Comment: Then why are you asking if there's a better way - you seem to already know the answer to this question :-)